цикл для вектора и двусвязного списка
Почему здесь не подходит знак <? В условии нужно использовать !=
for (list<int>::iterator i = a.begin(); i < a.end(); i++){
    
}

Хотя в векторе можно и с помощью знака <
for (vector<int>::iterator i = a.begin(); i < a.end(); i++){

}


Представьте, что у вас есть два адреса узлов связного списка.
Разве по этим адресам вы можете сказать, что один из узлов идёт раньше другого ("меньше")?
Очевидно - не можете. Вот и сравнивать соответствующие итераторы имеет смысл только на равенство/неравенство

А с вектором что? Разве адреса не могут быть меньше друг друга? В плане, это же просто шестнадцатеричные числа.

Тело вектора лежит в памяти последовательно, поэтому и адреса растут последовательно. И итератор не обязан быть адресом элемента - например, он может быть индексом.

получается, элементы списка лежат хаотично в памяти?

В общем случае - да. Может так сложиться, что будут выделяться последовательные адреса, но это не гарантировано.

Язык C++ запрещает сравнивать адреса если не они не указывают в общий массив. В данном больше/меньше запрещено. От себя добавлю что в случае списка a.end() может оказаться меньше любого итератора на реальный элемент.
